# How to create Multiple bot log-in in one page using VBS

Tags: vbscript, login-script, autologin

Need assistance on how to create multiple bot log-in using vbs in one webpage only.

For single bot log-in below is what I have tried- can someone edit this to create multiple?

Thanks in advance!

```
Set a = createobject ("wscript.shell")
a.run "http://yahoo.com"
wscript.sleep (5000)
a.sendkeys ("username")
a.sendkeys chr (9)
wscript.sleep (2000)
a.sendkeys ("password")
a.sendkeys "{Enter}"
call msgbox ("Finished")
wscript.quit
```

=this only launches 1 login :(

Comment: It fulfils `usernamepassword` into the yahoo search box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for loop for multiple log-in and use array value for username and pwd.

```
Dim uname(5) 'assign user name value to array element 0 to 5
Dim pwd(5)  'assign password value to array element 0 to 5   

Set a = createobject ("wscript.shell")
For i=0 to 5 step 1
a.run "http://yahoo.com"
wscript.sleep (5000)
a.sendkeys uname(i)
a.sendkeys chr (9)
wscript.sleep (2000)
a.sendkeys pwd(i)
a.sendkeys "{Enter}"
call msgbox ("Finished")
Next
wscript.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use one more array of url like

```
Dim ArrUrl(5) 
and assign value like 
ArrUrl(0) = "www.yahoo.com" 
ArrUrl(1) = "www.gmail.com" 
ArrUrl(2) "www.facebook.com"
```

....

and then use it in loop instead static value

```
a.run ArrUrl(i)
```